# TabbedPageWithNavigation in Xamarin.Forms fails with many tabs

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get Navigation working on Tabbed pages, which works fine as long as the tabs don't overflow into the More... Menu.
Edit: Originally, I though this was from the Xamarin.Forms samples at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/ before I realised the sample actually comes from https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage/ .

When running the TabbedPageWithNavigation on iOS, if you duplicate the NavigationPage elements in `MainPage.xaml` :

```
<NavigationPage Title="Schedule" Icon="schedule.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:SchedulePage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

until one of these duplicates appears in the `More...` menu, the Navigation no longer works.

You can get a full version of this with the `NavigationPage` elements pre-added at https://github.com/craigmj/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage .

I'm building with Xamarin Studio 6.2 on a Mac, Xcode 8.3.1 (12170), Xamarin.iOS
Version 10.4.0.123 (Xamarin Studio Community) Build date 2017-02-16 17:40:00-0500 and running on a iPhone emulator (I've tried a few and the same issues occurs).

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info to help reproduce (OS version, Xamarin Forms version, VS version)? If this is based on the samples on github, the best way to get help would be to fork the sample, reproduce your issue, and provide a link to that repository here.

Comment: I thought I was going mad - couldn't find the TabbedPageWithNavigationPage in the Xamarin.Forms samples, then I realised that it wasn't from the github samples, but from the website samples. I've updated the post.

Comment: I can confirm the behavior you're seeing. I'm guessing this is because the page is not connected to the actual navigation stack when it's loaded from the More menu. The next step is probably stepping through the Xamarin Forms code itself. I will try to look into it, but maybe someone with a bit more experience will have a better answer.

Comment: I think I'd recommend reporting this on the Xamarin Forms or opening and issue on Github, especially since you've already creating a project to reproduce the issue. Perhaps there is a known work-around, but it seems like an issue to me.